# Python: WebDriverWait button not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

It clicks show-more-results button. I have used WebDriverWait so that it allows the page to load but no use.

html:

```
 <div class="powerball_stats_list">
    <div id="loading-box"></div>
    <button id="more-btn" class="btn_list_more" type="button">more data</button>
 </div>
```

python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='more-btn' class='btn_list_more' type='button']")))
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='more-btn' class='btn_list_more' type='button']")))
        click=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='more-btn' class='btn_list_more' type='button']")))
        try:
            click.click()
        except WebDriverException:
            print "Page not loaded Correctly. Try again."
            break
    except (TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException, ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException):
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is incorrect as these predicates `class='btn_list_more' type='button'` are not allowed in XPath. Try

```
"//button[@id='more-btn' and @class='btn_list_more' and @type='button']"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.
error : Page not loaded Correctly. Try again.